# php and POST - not getting through

Tags: php, apache, post

I have an android app that does a POST request to my php website which then saves that data

It works fine for one phone from 1 place but not from another phone from another place (using different wifi networks).  I've looked in the /var/log/apache2/access.log and can see the requests from the working one but no requests from the non-working one.  Is it possible apache is blocking them?  Are refused POST requests stored somewhere else?

Comment: You may have some info in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Or you could plug your 2nd Android phone in and use adb to check the app's logs.

Comment: My first inclination would be to check for firewalls.

Comment: thanks for both comments - I think it is probably the firewall but I should interpret the return message from the http_send.